# How to display the answer direction for a questionarie based on Direction

Tags: angularjs

We are creating a quiz using angularjs.
We want to show the radiobutton list direction vertically or horizontally.
If it is horizontally we want do show in 2 columns.
Help me to show horizontally or vertically

Have provided the code in

```js
  var app = angular.module("quizApp", []);

        app.controller("quizCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.questions = [
                {
                    question: "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
                    options: ["India", "USA", "China", "Russia"],
                    answer: 2,
                    direction:0
                },
                {
                    question: "When did the second world war end?",
                    options: ["1945", "1939", "1944", "1942"],
                    answer: 0,
                    direction: 1
                }
            ];
        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="quizApp" ng-controller="quizCtrl">
        <div data-ng-repeat="quiz in questions track by $index" data-ng-init="quizIndex = $index" layout="column">
            <div layout="row">
                <span data-ng-bind="quiz.question"></span>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" data-ng-repeat="option in quiz.options track by $index" data-ng-init="optionIndex = $index">
                <input type="radio" data-ng-value="{{option}}" style="margin-right: 5px;"
                                name="Options_{{quizIndex}}_Response_{{optionIndex}}" />
                 <span id="spnAnswer_{{quizIndex}}_{{optionIndex}}" data-ng-bind="option" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class in the div of your repeater to show horizontal or vertical way.

Your HTML template might be look like following:

```
<div ng-class="'class-for-horizontal-display': !showVertical, 'class-for-vertical-display': showVertical" data-ng-repeat="quiz in questions track by $index" data-ng-init="quizIndex = $index" layout="column">

    </div>
```

and in your controller you should have a $scope variable "showVertical" like:

```
$scope.showVertical = false
```